# bash terminal problem lsb-release

Tags: gnome-terminal

When I get to my bash-terminal, I have the following error

```
etc/update-motd.d/80-esm lsb_release not found
```

Do you know please how to solve this problem ??

Regards,

Comment: Make sure that you have installed `lsb-release` package.

Comment: I did that but it does not work .

Comment: I used sudo apt-get install lsb-release and also sudo apt-get install lsb-core

Comment: close and open another terminal